# A Robocopy job to copy files from VM Windows 2003 to a windows 2008 DFS Share over WAN

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, virtual-machines, dfs, robocopy

I have the following in a bat file running as a scheduled task on the VM Windows 2003 server

```
robocopy "d:\Folder\Sub folder" "\\prod.local\shareddata\Loc\Folder\SubFolder" /S /R:0 /W:5 /NP /NS /NFL /LOG+:RobocopyI.log
```

There are about 10,000 files and 42 folders in the source occupying about 13Gb but it's taking a long time to run, around 20 hours.

Can anyone see if there's any way of improving on the time taken? I've done a bit of reasearch on the robocopy switches but I'm not sure if I've got them quite right.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are doing this over a WAN, you might try using the /MIR option instead ot skip previously copied files if you are doing a repeat process over and over.  In more modern versions of Windows (2008+), DFS offers the ability to do this in real time as files are changed and are synced over automatically.  I've used Robocopy over a high speed WAN link (50Mbps) and it worked fine, but if you are dealing with something slow, you probably just have to wait...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, upgrade your 2003 operating system to something made in the last 10 years.  2008R2 and above come with a multi-threaded version of robocopy, which improves the transfer time of jobs consisting of thousands of little files by orders of magnitude.

Or if you won't do that, use another file copy program like RichCopy or something that advertises multithreaded capabilities.

Also, make sure you're on a gigabit network and not a 100Mbps one.